# Replace static array with results from query

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Please see the php function below.  I am trying to get the results of my query to display as an array in the same format as the static array shown below. How would I replace that static array with results from my query?  Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT event_id, event_name FROM events ORDER by event_id";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

function get_price($find){
    $books=array(
        "java"=>266,
        "c"=>250,
        "php"=>320
        );

    foreach($books as $book=>$price)
    {
        if($book==$find)
        {
            return $price;
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your example is a bit unclear... First your code goed towards 'events', but then you're going with 'books'... What is it exactly?

Comment: @Raphioly-San I am trying to make $books = the sql array results.  Thats it

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated: Normally you would create an array then fill it with all the items  found in the database (or whatever source you're going to fetch it from).

Side note: Instructing the MySQLi extension to fetch both associative and numeric is a bit time-wasting (and consuming, because the processor has to spend cycles on both).

It would look something like this:

```
$array = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) { // fetch as object, nicer ;)
    $array[$result->title] = $result->price;
}
```

The array would now look something like:

```
$array = [
    'Jungle book' => 26.95,
    'Mowgli' => 24.75,
    'Fantastic Four - E.12-6' => 100
];
```

Comment: im trying to replace the part of the function that says $books=array(
    "java"=>266,
    "c"=>250,
    "php"=>320
    ); with the SQL results

Comment: Then initialize the array `$array = []` with whatever you want in there and still run it as above...